# Compile a third-party library also using SCons from SCons build script

Tags: parallel-processing, scons, build-system

I'm using SCons to build my project.

A third-party library I've integrated also uses SCons, but it can be updated from Git at any time and I've got no control over the contents of its `SConstruct` file.

When compiled on its own, the library's `SConstruct` file accepts the parameters `bits=32/64` and `target=debug/release`

I tried building it with `env.SConscript()`, but this doesn't pass the parameters in a form that the target `SConstruct` file accepts (without using SCons' `Import()` function):

```
# Compile Godot-CPP, a wrapper library we depend on
if nuclex._is_debug_build(environment):
    compile_godot_cpp = environment.SConscript(
        'addons/godot-cpp/SConstruct', export='bits=64 target=debug'
    )
else:
    compile_godot_cpp = environment.SConscript(
        'addons/godot-cpp/SConstruct', export='bits=64 target=release'
    )
```

Can I compile another `SConstruct` file and pass parameters to it as if SCons had been invoked from the command line on its own?

I'm aware that I could just use `env.Command()` to start another SCons process, but then SCons couldn't parallelize the build (i.e. `scons -j16`) like it does in the case of `env.SConscript()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a good way to do this beyond Command().
You might ask the godot project if they could move the bulk of their logic into a SConscript at the top level which you could then import and somehow pass the needed parameters to.